# Batch script for MKVExtract?

Tags: script, batch-file, matroska

I was wondering if anyone can help me writing a simple batch script that runs this command:

```
mkvextract *.mkv 2:
```

For all mkv files inside a folder.
mkvextract doesn't seem to work with folders or *.mkv syntax, so it needs the full name and directory of the file.

I guess the script has to retrieve this info and run the command for each file that fits the profile.

I don't know how to approach this in Windows, but I've seem something like that for Linux here: https://gist.github.com/kampfgnu/bb7be04b624ed5ddf65d6e7c54f9ce2e

How can I do this with cmd/powershell? Thanks.

Comment: Give `FOR %A IN ("C:\Folder\Path\*.mkv") DO mkvextract %~A 2:` from a command line.... a try..... this is simply using a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop iterating the files to the command accordingly. If you need it as a batch script then you have to double the percent signs as such: `FOR %%A IN ("C:\Folder\Path\*.mkv") DO mkvextract %%~A 2:`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It seems to work with a .bat file.

I finished it as: 
     `FOR %%A IN ("D:\folder\*.mkv") DO mkvpropedit -v "%%~A" -v --edit track:2 --set track-number=3 --edit track:3 --set track-number=2`

Which is batch altering track numbers in a mkv file. Thanks again.

By the way, where can I learn more of this command scripting language for Windows?

Comment: No problem, I will be happy to add as an answer too. You might look over the **Series Parts** on the  [Guide to Windows Batch Scripting](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/) post and look over that as a starting guide. Also, from command line, just test various commands and use the `/?` switch to see the details of each command and just create small test scripts, commands, etc. and test as I think that's really the best way to learn after reading the basics seeing everything in action. For example from command line run `FOR /?`, or `DIR /?`, or any `<command> /?`